# Null model passed in MVC to controller when form is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am using MVC4 application, and there is one controller for allowing user to input some data. The thing is I am getting null values in all the properties returned from the form. I am using strongly typed model and I did not see any name collisions as suggested in few posts about null model being passed. 
Heres my Model

```
public class NewsItemView
{

    [Required]
    public string NewsTitle;

    public string NewsAuthor;

    public string NewsSummary;

    public string NewsDescription;

    public bool NewsAllowComments;

    [Required]
    public string NewsContent;

    public string NewsSourceName;
}
```

Controller Action(get)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        NewsItemView nv = new NewsItemView();
        return View(nv);
    }
```

View:

```
@model NewsItemView

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Service", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "NewsForm" }))
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsTitle)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsTitle)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsAuthor)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsAuthor)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsAllowComments)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsAllowComments)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsSummary)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsSummary)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsDescription)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsDescription)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsContent)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsContent)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsSourceName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsSourceName)

<br />

<button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Create News</button>

}
```

Controller Action(post)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(NewsItemView newsModel)
    {
     //my code here
    }
```

If i use FormsCollection, I am able to extract the values using index, any idea why the strongly typed model is not working?

Comment: Can you show request that is sent to your Create action?

Comment: The only thing I can think is that you don't have a constructor for the model which takes no parameters, but the code you've posted looks ok for that.

Comment: @ChrisRedhead this is what default constructor stands for.

Comment: Looks like model binding messing things up. Can you try changing your model post function deceleration to something like this public ActionResult Create(NewsItemView m)

Comment: Aren't you missing the getters and the setters on the model properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue on my environment and all what I have done to fix it is just updating the model fields to be properties like the following

```
public class NewsItemViewModel
{

    [Required]
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }

    public string NewsAuthor { get; set; }

    public string NewsSummary { get; set; }

    public string NewsDescription { get; set; }

    public bool NewsAllowComments { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NewsContent { get; set; }

    public string NewsSourceName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hossam. It did not come to my notice before.